# Access Time to completion from Dask Task Stream

Tags: python, time, dask, dask-distributed

I am using Dask Futures to speed up a Monte Carlo process in python, and am looking to improve the code by displaying a "time remaining" feature to the user.  My idea is to somehow grab the time to completion from the previous completed tasks executed by futures to estimate this time remaining value. I see this timing information displayed in the dask scheduler GUI, but is there some way of grabbing this in python code so I can utilize it? Any feedback on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a scheduler local to your process (this is commonly the case if you are using LocalCluster at `client.cluster.scheduler`) then you might want to look at the `.total_occupancy` attribute.  If you want to go into more detail then check out `.task_groups`

Comment: Thank you for the reply @MRocklin! I had a chance to try out these functions but was unsure what the output means, and there is no documentation on both of these functions.  The .total_occupancy attribute outputs a single float number.  Im guessing this is the "total occupancy", but I don't really know what that means.